# WPF cannot access nested control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Wondering if there's any trick to accessing a nested control in the code-behind ?

given some XAML along the lines of

```
<UserControl>    
    <textbox />
    <DataGrid Name="MyGrid">
        <Columns>
            <Column field=ABC>
                <EditType>
                    <ComboBox Name="myCombo1"/>
```

I can access this.MyGrid but cannot access this.myCombo1 !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime that I have run into this I have be able to resolve it by using [`x:Name`](http://wpf.2000things.com/2010/10/15/95-xname-vs-name/) instead of [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290.aspx). This may not be the issue in your case but give it a try.

Comment: pretty strange, did not work for me ! I'm using vs2010 sp1, .net 4

Comment: @Kumar The example that you gave doesn't compile either I am missing some namespace or not knowing what control you are using for sure, can you give a more complete example that can be dropped into an UserControl and tested?

Comment: the sample uses devx wpf controls, i can upload more if you have those or are willing/able to install their trial versions

Comment: @Kumar Sorry I do not have those library's, am downloading trial now

Comment: @Kumar I have the controls now if you want please post a more complete example

Comment: I can't add an attachment here, any help on where i can post this ?

Comment: @Kumar Try http://pastebin.com/ that is where I usually see code links pointing to

Comment: here you are http://pastebin.com/pdRH4r0c though that only has text, will see if i can post the .zip elsewhere

Comment: here's the complete project http://www.sendspace.com/file/gp69gh  if you open up nested1.xaml, view code, you cannot access cmbTypes from the code, i've tried using x:Name as well but same result, thanks for your help !

Comment: @Kumar I have looked at what you posted. The first thing that jumps out at me is your checkbox is inside of a template, therefore it will not be generated until you load data, also there will be one for each row. What you can do is add an event i.e. click to the checkbox and set a breakpoint on it and  look at your sender object to see if you can figure out how to access. I was not able to take it any further since I don't have the datastore.

Answer (score 0):

In simple cases you can access elements using their name, but looks like combobox is datatemplate part, you can work with visual tree at runtime using [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx), but if you use mvvm & code right usually you don't need to access elements directly. Can you provide more information on general problem or test project to reproduce issue?